# Android Google Maps API in Release not working

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a read a dozen of questions and answers and also watched some YouTube Videos. But my Android App with Google Maps Release Version aint working.

What I have done until now:

1. Get the SHA-1 Code (Yes, its the correct one)
2. Register in Google Developer
3. Create new Project
4. Set in the SHA-1
5. Set in the Package Name and Project (Yes, its the correct one)
6. Get the key
7. Set the key in google project under google_maps_key to String

The string is linked in the manifest file. But its still not working...! Any ideas?

Comment: what is your `logcat` showing ??

Comment: are you using release keystore's SHA1.  If u have generated SHA1 using debug keystore then it wont work in release keystore.

Comment: May be you need to `Generate SHA-1` with `Release Mode`. We need your `Logcat` shoot here with exception.

Comment: If how explained on http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/obtaining-sha1-fingerprint-android-keystore/ is correct. Then I did it wrong the whole time. The key I have is for debug and not for the release. Im going to check that this evening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different keys one for debug and another for release.

Use this link to generate the release SHA-1 key.

http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/obtaining-sha1-fingerprint-android-keystore/.

Here is the official documentation.

https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158862?hl=en#creating-android-api-keys

Answer (score 1):

When you try to release APK, Use SHA-1 of the KeyStore not default or current SHA-1 of WorkSpace.

Some developer uses testing API key for app which is generated for default keystore, but not it don't know for release version need to generate new API key accouding new SHA-1 of keystore.

So
Generate New API key for releasing APK (KeyStore SHA-1).